# SQL compare 3rd number aftee decimal point

Tags: sql, sybase

I want to select myNum from myTable where myNum's 3rd number after decimal point is above 0.

So

123.456 would be returned.

123.450 would not.

(sybase)

Comment: you would expect a user with 27K+ rep to be able to either figure this out or at least search for it.

Comment: @MitchWheat jeepers wrong side of the bed, your comment doesn't work by the way, it should be last digit.

Comment: nope and it depends whether toy are talking about ints or strings

Comment: @MitchWheat you are the only person to mention string.

Comment: correct: also according to this http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1540/doc/html/san1278452945834.html there is a MOD() function in sybase

Comment: @MitchWheat yeah thanks, if you read to the bottom of the actual doc page it explains why I don't have access to it.

Comment: @MitchWheat Maybe his rep comes from tags having nothing to do with SQL?  I myself have asked some very basic questions about Angular JS over the last year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT myNum
FROM myTable
WHERE FLOOR(myNum*1000) % 10 > 0
```

**Explanation:**

Seeing is believing, so given the input `123.456`:

```
myNum*1000 = 123456.xx   (possibly data last 3rd decimal place)
FLOOR(myNum*1000) = 123456
FLOOR(myNum*1000) % 10 = 6, which is greater than zero
```

Comment: I have no mod but this works select 123.456*1000%10;

Comment: @NimChimpsky You might also want to take the floor, in case you have data past the 3rd decimal place.